Displaying Multiple Polygons in QGIS Server printing module
I am encountering an issue with printing multiple polygons in QGIS Server. Despite providing coordinates for multiple polygons in the request, only one of the polygons is being displayed on the generated map. I have verified the correctness of the coordinates and the request parameters, but the desired behavior is not being achieved.
Can anyone provide insights or troubleshooting steps to ensure that QGIS Server can successfully render and display multiple polygons on the map?
If possible, provide examples illustrating the correct formatting for multiple polygons within a single request.
http://localhost:8080/qgis-server/?
SERVICE=WMS
&LAYERS=hidden
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetPrint
&FORMAT=pdf
&CRS=EPSG:2154
&TEMPLATE=Basic
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x1 y1));POLYGON((x5 y5, x6 y6, x7 y7, x8 y8, x5 y5));POLYGON((x9 y9, x10 y10, x11 y11, x12 y12, x9 y9))
&map0:EXTENT=xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=<StyledLayerDescriptor><UserStyle><Name>Highlight</Name><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><Name>Symbol</Name><LineSymbolizer><Stroke><CssParameter name="stroke">%23ea1173</CssParameter><CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter><CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.6</CssParameter></Stroke></LineSymbolizer><PolygonSymbolizer><Fill><CssParameter name="fill">%23FFFF00</CssParameter><CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter></Fill></PolygonSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></StyledLayerDescriptor>
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSTRING=Write label here
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSIZE=16
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELCOLOR=%23000000
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERCOLOR=%23FFFFFF
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERSIZE=1.5

Result: only the first polygon is on the map

You need to have as many symbols and labels as there are highlighted geometries.
For instance, a GetMap request would be (2 geometries, 2 symbols, 2 labels):
http://localhost:8080/qgis-server/?REQUEST=GetMap&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
...
&HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x1 y1));POLYGON((x5 y5, x6 y6, x7 y7, x8 y8, x5 y5))
&HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=<StyledLayerDescriptor><UserStyle><Name>Highlight</Name><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><Name>Symbol</Name><LineSymbolizer><Stroke><SvgParameter name="stroke">%23ea1173</SvgParameter><SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</SvgParameter><SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1.6</SvgParameter></Stroke></LineSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></StyledLayerDescriptor>;
<StyledLayerDescriptor><UserStyle><Name>Highlight</Name><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><Name>Symbol</Name><LineSymbolizer><Stroke><SvgParameter name="stroke">%74ea6673</SvgParameter><SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</SvgParameter><SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</SvgParameter></Stroke></LineSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></StyledLayerDescriptor>
&HIGHLIGHT_LABELSTRING=Write label here;Or here

Symbols and labels parameters are separated by ; as it is done for the geometries. You can do the same for labels style.
